# Two way binding in XAML does not update source if we use expression interaction ChangepropertyAction

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have run into a scenario where I have to update the source data object in an WPF project WITHOUT any code behind (strictly XAML changes only). The description is as follow: I have two text boxes, calling them Name and Title of an Employee.

Employee.cs:

```
public class Employee : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string name;
    public string Name {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            name = value;
            if(PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Name"));
            }
        }
    }

    private string title;
    public string Title {
        get { return title; }
        set
        {
            title = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Title"));
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public static Employee GetEmployee()
    {
        var emp = new Employee()
        {
            Name = "Ali Ahmed",
            Title = "Developer"
        };
        return emp;
    }
}
```

The windows class is as follow:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Employee employee = Employee.GetEmployee();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = employee;
        }

        private void OnNameChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox castedTextBox = sender as TextBox;
            employee.Title = castedTextBox.Text;
        }
    }
```

Notice the `OnNameChanged` handler will set the employee's title to a string of his name (simulating an unwanted bug in actual project)

XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        xmlns:i = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" 
        xmlns:ei = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions" 
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <CheckBox x:Name="checkBox" Content="CheckBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="21" Margin="59,39,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="89"/>
        <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="59,72,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="179" />
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="TitleTextBox" Height="21" Margin="60,113,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Title, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="178">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
                    <ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetName="TitleTextBox" TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=TitleTextBox}" PropertyName="Text" Value=""/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </TextBox>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="24" Margin="60,146,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}" TextChanged="OnNameChanged" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="178"/>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="27" Margin="59,180,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="179"/>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="27" Margin="60,221,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Title, Mode=OneWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="179"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The only important thing about this XAML code is the usage of the interaction trigger on `TitleTextBox`. The intent and purpose of this block of interaction XAML code is to wipe out the title text box in hope that the TwoWay binding will also wipe out the value of the employee's title that was wrongly set the the `OnNameChanged` event above. However, it only wipes out the content of the box without actually updating the model object employee underneath.

My question: Is there something I could do on XAML  ***alone*** (since this is a specific constraint I have to work with) that could force the model to recognize the changes in the Title box and update the Employee object?

Comment: This trigger looks like an endless loop: when the Text property changes it clears the text property and the binding is lost because it is overwritten by a constant value (empty string). So this changes the Text which triggers the trigger again.

Comment: Indeed. Somehow, Microsoft has a way to guard against this endless loop though (I put a break point in the Employee.cs class, it doesn't get hit endlessly). What I am seeing is that the textbox got cleared, but the source is never updated. Is there a way that I could (endlessly) update the source and UI text? If there is such a way, perhaps, I could cook up a way in the actual project to perform the tactical fix (XAML fix without code behind). Vote up for the endless loop logic plot-hole spotted.

Comment: My guess is that the endless loop in this case is broken by overwriting the binding with a constant value and that this is also the reason why the view model is not updated: the binding is gone.